# Heisenberg group modulo prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, heisenberg-group

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p), the Heisenberg group modulo $p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, has the presentation
$$H(\mathbb{F}_p)=\langle x,y,z\mid x^p=y^p=z^p=1, \ xz=zx, \ yz=zy, \ z=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\rangle.$$
I could even derive it, but the proof seems to work modulo any integer, not just an odd prime. Why should $p$ be an odd prime? (If it works modulo any integer, it seems a little strange that the Wikipedia article insists on $p$ being an odd prime.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Heisenberg group can be defined over any commutative unital ring. It is the group of all uni-upper- triangular matrices over that ring. If the ring is the ring of integers modulo some $n$ you get your group. Traditionally, though,  people assume $n=p$ to be prime. Then the group is one of two nonabelian groups of order $p^3$.

Comment: does it satisfy the same generator/relation presentation though when $p$ is not prime?

Comment: Yes, if rhe ring is the ring of integers mod $n$. For an arbitrary ring it may be not finitetely generated. Usual cases are ring of all integers or a field. If it is the field of real numbers you get the Lie group Nil.